# C++: Use #if std::is_fundamental<T>::value for conditional compilation in MSVC 2010

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation, type-traits

In my template I need to have different code parts based on whether the typename is a fundamental type or not.

Compiling this code gives a C4067 in MSVC (unexpected tokens following preprocessor directive - expected a newline):

```
template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::foo()
{
// ... some code here
#if std::is_fundamental<T>::value
    if(m_buf[j] < m_buf[idx_min])
        idx_min = j;
#else
    const ASSortable& curr = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[j]);
    const ASSortable& curr_min = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[idx_min]);
    // error checking removed for simplicity
    if(curr.before(curr_min))
        idx_min = j;
}
#endif
```

The template is to work with both primitive and my own (derived from ASSortable) data types and the error is thrown from template instantiation code:

```
template class MyClass<char>;
```

Trying to modify the precompiler expression to this didn't work either:

```
#if std::is_fundamental<T>::value == true
```

and produces the same exact warning.

Any ideas how to make this code warning-free?

**Edit** Another thing that comes to mind is to convert this into a run-time check and live with the "constant if expression" warning... Is there really no way to do this elegantly in a *single* function with no specializations and no extra bloat?

**Edit #2** So the way I solved this (which was obvious, but somehow escaped me...) was to define a `bool ASSortable::operator<(const ASSortable& _o) const {return this->before(_o);};` which does the job and makes the code clean (once again).

No more `if`s or `#ifdef`s or any similar clutter in my code!

Can't believe I even asked that question as it had such an obvious and simple answer :(

Comment: Couldn't you use a specialization of `MyClass`?

Comment: I'm trying not to pollute the implementation with too many specializations. Consider that MyClass will be specialized for quite a few fundamental types and the code gets messy way too soon (the specialization will cover char/short/int/long/long long and their unsigned counterparts, float/double/long double) so I'd really rather just have a conditional compilation instead of copying blocks of code for each specialization of a fundamental type

Comment: @YePhIcK You can always use `enable_if` to prevent specializing a class for one specialized overload. My solution does that.

Comment: All the below solutions are valid, however I probably will end up not using any of them for the following reason:
Debugging programs is at least twice as hard as writing them, so if you are writing a program at the edge of your abilities...

I believe in simple code that doesn't require expert level to read/comprehend. Too bad there's no elegant solution to my problem.

Comment: Why would you even define an `ASSortable` interface? We already have `operator<`.

Answer (score 2):

The common pattern to solve that issue is moving the function to a base class that is specialized and abusing inheritance to bring it to your scope:

```
template <typename T, bool is_fundamental>
struct Foo_impl {
   void foo() {
   }
};
template <typename T>
struct Foo_impl<T,true>
{
   void foo() {              // is fundamental version
   }
};
template <typename T>
class Foo : public Foo_impl<T, std::is_fundamental_type<T>::value> {
   // ...
};
```

Another approach would be to implement those as private functions in your class and dispatch to them internally from `foo` based on the trait. This is really simple and a cleaner solution, but fails if one of the two versions of the `foo_impl` will not compile. In that case you can use, as others have suggested a template member function to resolve, **but** I would still offer the non-templated `foo` as the public interface, forwarding to a private `foo_impl` template. The reason is that the `template` in there is an implementation detail to *hack* conditional compilation, not part of the interface. You don't want user code calling that member function with different template arguments than the type of your own class. Borrowing from pmr's answer:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  template <typename U = T, 
            typename std::enable_if< 
              std::is_fundamental<U>::value, int >::type* _ = 0
           >
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "is fundamental" << std::endl;
  }
//...
```

That solution allows user code like:

```
Foo<int> f;
f.foo<std::string>();
```

Which will instantiate a function that you don't need nor want, and will execute the logic that you don't want. Even if users don't try to fool your class, the fact that is a template in the interface might be confusing and make users think that it is possible to call it for different types.

Comment: Yes, that is a real problem with my solution. Yours is a lot safer and cleaner API wise.

Answer (score 1):

Preproccessor is run at an early stage of compilation, before the compiler analyzes the types and knows the meaning of `std::is_fundamental<T>::value`, hence it cannot work this way.

Instead, use specialization:

```
template<bool> void f();

template<> void f<true>() {
    if(m_buf[j] < m_buf[idx_min])
        idx_min = j;
}

template<> void f<false>() {
    const ASSortable& curr = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[j]);
    const ASSortable& curr_min = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[idx_min]);
    // error checking removed for simplicity
    if(curr.before(curr_min))
        idx_min = j;
}

template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::foo()
{
// ... some code here
    f<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>();
}
```

**EDIT:** You're likely to need to make `f` a member function, however it's not directly possible since `MyClass<T>` is a non-specialized template. You could make `f` a global which delegates the call to the correct member of `MyClass`. However, there is another approach.

Using overloading, this becomes:

```
void MyClass<T>::f(const true_type&) {
    if(m_buf[j] < m_buf[idx_min])
        idx_min = j;
}

void MyClass<T>::f(const false_type&) {
    const ASSortable& curr = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[j]);
    const ASSortable& curr_min = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[idx_min]);
    // error checking removed for simplicity
    if(curr.before(curr_min))
        idx_min = j;
}

template <typename T>
void MyClass<T>::foo()
{
// ... some code here
    f(std::is_fundamental<T>::type());
}
```

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: incorrect, they aren't getting instantiated unless you explicitly instantiate them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up states of compilation. The preprocessor is run before the actual compiler and has no knowledge of types or templates. It just performs (very) sophisticated text substitution.

There is nothing such as `static if`<sup>1</sup> in current C++, so you have to resort to a different method to enable conditional compilation. For functions I would prefer `enable_if`.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  template <typename U = T, 
            typename std::enable_if< 
              std::is_fundamental<U>::value, int >::type = 0
           >
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "is fundamental" << std::endl;
  }

  template <typename U = T, 
            typename std::enable_if< 
              !(std::is_fundamental<U>::value), int >::type = 0
           >
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "is not fundamental" << std::endl;
  }
};


struct x {};

int main()
{
  Foo<int> f; f.foo();
  Foo<x> f2; f2.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> References:

[Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer): Static if presented by Alexandrescu in Going Native.

[n3322](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3322.pdf): Walter E. Brown's proposal for `static if`

[n3329](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3329.pdf): Sutter, Bright and Alexandrescu's proposal for `static if`

Comment: Too bad `static if` is not going to be available any time soon :(

Comment: @YePhIcK: `static if` has problems of it's own. It would allow certain constructs that can be confusing to the user and hard to track by the compiler. I cannot recall the details, but it boilds down to the fact that until instantiation of a template (second phase of lookup) the actual contents of the type are unknown (some fields or properties might be changed by the `static if` statements)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much what it says, you can't use `::` in preprocessor directives. Actually, the only thing you can use after `#if` is a constant-expression that is defined before the compile-time. You can find some info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`std::is_fundamental<T>::value == true` cannot be used at pre-processing time. I guess you would have to use some SFINAE trick with std::enable_if:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, void>::type 
MyClass<T>::foo()
{
    // ... some code here

    if(m_buf[j] < m_buf[idx_min])
        idx_min = j;
}


template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value, void>::type 
MyClass<T>::foo()
{
    // ... some code here

    const ASSortable& curr = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[j]);
    const ASSortable& curr_min = dynamic_cast<ASSortable&>(m_buf[idx_min]);
    // error checking removed for simplicity
    if(curr.before(curr_min))
        idx_min = j;
}
```

Comment: Afaik this won't work unless you make `foo` depend on a template parameter.